# How to construct data structure with variable size elements

Tags: python, construct

I am trying to construct the structure with variable size of the element `value` from class `val` :

```
from construct import *

TEST = Struct("test",
           UInt8("class"),
           Embed(switch(lambda ctx: ctx.class) {
             1: UInt8("value"),
             2: UInt16("value"),
             3: UInt32("value")}
            ))
          )
```

The above code is incorrect.

I need to achieve something like this: If the class is 1 then one byte will be received from the packet.

Comment: You should note that this code uses Construct 2.5 which is ancient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple [format string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters) to change `struct` behaviour and `struct.unpack_from` with `struct.calcsize` to continue parsing bytearray from the end of the last found byte sequence:

```
import struct
v1 = bytearray([0x00,0xFF])
v2 = bytearray([0x01,0xFF,0xFF])
v3 = bytearray([0x02,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF])

v = v2 # change this

header_format = 'B'
body_format_variants = {0:'B',1:'H',2:'L'}

header = struct.unpack_from(header_format,v,0)
body = struct.unpack_from(body_format_variants[header[0]],v,struct.calcsize(header_format))

print (header, body, "size=",struct.calcsize('>'+header_format+body_format_variants[header[0]]))
```